# jslint - jslint4java - how to skip checking Required Blocks condition in javascript

Tags: jslint, jslint4java, gjslint

I must use a condition like this in my Javascript code

```
if (condition) statement;
```

but it returns an error

> (" Expected '{' and instead saw ' '. ")

while validating using jslint4java. Is there is any way to skip this checking?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  The way to find out is to visit [jslint.com](http://jslint.com/) and see what option you can use, then pass that option to jslint4java.  But I've just checked and none of the options appear to do what you want.